# Given a Morse String with out any spaces, how to find the no. of words it can represent irrespective of the meaning

Tags: java, string, recursion, dynamic-programming, morse-code

Given A morse String eg. aet = ".- . -" if the spaces are removed it will become an ambiguous morse string ".-.-" which can represent "aet","eta","ent","etet" etc.

the problem is to find the no.of words that the morse string without spaces can represent irrespective of the meaning of the words. The constraint is that the new word which is formed should be the same size of the input i.e "aet" = "ent" and other words like "etet" should be discarded.

i implemented a recursive solution for some reason it is not working. below is my code and thinking of converting this to DP approach to increase time efficiency. Can some one help to point out the mistake in the below code and is DP a right approach to follow for this problem? Thanks in advance!!

EDIT 1 :- The program gives me an output but not the correct one. for ex. for the morse String representing aet = ".- . -" if given without any spaces to the program ".-.-" it should give an out put "3" i.e 3 words can be formed that is of the same size as the input including the input "aet","eta","ent" but it gives me an output "1". I think there is some thing wrong with the recursive calls.

The approach used here is to simply cut the morse string in a place where first valid morse code is encountered and the repeat the process with the rest of the string untill 3 such valid morse code are found and check whether whole morse string is consumed. if consumed increment the word count and repeat the process for different values of substring size(end variable in the below code).

I hope this helps!!.Tried my best to explain as clearly as I could.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;


    public class MorseCode2 {
    static Map<String,String> morseCode;
    static Map<String,String> morseCode2;
    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] alpha = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",
                          "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v",
                          "w","x","y","z"};
        String[] morse = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",
                      ".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
        morseCode = new HashMap<String,String>();
        morseCode2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<26;i++){
            morseCode.put(morse[i],alpha[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<26;i++){
            morseCode2.put(alpha[i],morse[i]);
        }

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();
        String morseString = "";

        for(int j = 0; j< input.length(); j++){
            morseString += morseCode2.get(input.charAt(j)+"");
        }

            countPossibleWord(morseString,input.length(),0,1,0);




        System.out.println(count);

        in.close();
    }

    public static void countPossibleWord(String s,int inputSize,int  start,int end,int tempCount){

        if(start >= s.length() || end > s.length()){
            return;
        }
        if(tempCount>inputSize){
            return;
        }
        String sub  = s.substring(start, end);
        if(sub.length()>4){
            return;
        }
        if(morseCode.get(sub)!=null){
            tempCount++;
            countPossibleWord(s,inputSize,end,end+1,tempCount);
        }
        else{
            countPossibleWord(s,inputSize,start,end+1,tempCount);
        }

        if(tempCount == inputSize && end == s.length()){
            count++;
        }


        countPossibleWord(s,inputSize,start,end+1,0);

    }

}
```

EDIT 2 :- Thank you all for your Responses and Extremely sorry for the confusing code, will surely try to improve on writing neat and clear code. learnt a lot from your replies!!

And i also some how made the code work, the problem was I passed wrong argument which changed the state of the recursive calls. Instead of passing "tempCount-1" for the last argument in the last function call in the method "countPossibleWord" i passed "0" this altered the state. found this after running through the code manually for larger inputs. below is the corrected method

```
    public static void countPossibleWord(String s,int inputSize,int   start,int end,int tempCount){
        if(start >= s.length() || end > s.length()){
            return;
        }
        if(tempCount>inputSize){
            return;
        }
        String sub  = s.substring(start, end);
        if(sub.length()>4){
            return;
        }
        if(morseCode.get(sub)!=null){
            tempCount++;
            countPossibleWord(s,inputSize,end,end+1,tempCount);
        }
        else{
            countPossibleWord(s,inputSize,start,end+1,tempCount);
        }

        if(tempCount == inputSize && end == s.length()){
            count++;
        }


        countPossibleWord(s,inputSize,start,end+1,tempCount-1);

    }
```

}

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description with which we can do anything. What does your code do and exactly how does it differ from the desired? Please edit your question and specify.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. (quoted from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: countPossibleWord() does not return anything. Shouldn't it return the number of counted words?

Comment: Question edited. I hope its clear

Comment: i've made the "count" variable as a class variable. @thomas weller

Comment: Thank you for your response :) @thomas weller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to have a recursive function, you should be clear about your parameters (use as few as possible) as well as when to step down and when to go up again. 
My solution would look something like

```
public static int countPossibleWord(String strMorse, String strAlpha, int inputSize) {
    if (strMorse.length() > 0) {  // still input to process
        if (strAlpha.length() >= inputSize)
            return 0; // String already has wrong size
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < morse.length; i++) { // try all morse codes
            if (strMorse.startsWith(morse[i])) { // on the beginning of the given string
                count += countPossibleWord(strMorse.substring(morse[i].length()), strAlpha+alpha[i], inputSize);
            }
        }
        return count;
    } else {
        if( strAlpha.length() == inputSize ) {
            System.out.println( strAlpha );
            return 1; // one solution has been found
        } else {
            return 0; // String has wrong size
        }
    }
}
```

Your morse and alpha arrays need to be static variables for this to work.
Note that there is only one situation where the recursion will step down: when there is some input left and the size limit is not reached. Then it will check for the next possible letter in the loop.

All other cases will lead the recursion to go one step up again - and when going up, it will return the number of solutions found.

Call it like this:

```
System.out.println(countPossibleWord(morseString, "", input.length() ));
```

Comment: Thank you!! for your valuble suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, that you don't understand it any more, because it's not clean as described by Robert C. Martin. Compare your code to the following. This is certainly still not the cleanest, but I think you can understand what it does. Tell me if you don't.

Consider this main program:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String morsetext = enterTextOnConsole();        
        MorseTable morseTable = new MorseTable();
        MorseCode code = convertToMorseCodeWithoutSpaces(morsetext, morseTable);        
        List<String> guesses = getAllPossibleMeanings(code, morseTable);        
        List<String> guessesOfSameLength = filterForSameLength(morsetext, guesses);
        printListOnConsole(guessesOfSameLength);
    }

    private static void printListOnConsole(List<String> guessesOfSameLength) {
        for (String text : guessesOfSameLength) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> filterForSameLength(String morsetext, List<String> guesses) {
        List<String> guessesOfSameLength = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (String guess : guesses) {
            if (guess.length() == morsetext.length())
            {
                guessesOfSameLength.add(guess);
            }
        }
        return guessesOfSameLength;
    }

    private static List<String> getAllPossibleMeanings(MorseCode code, MorseTable morseTable) {
        MorseCodeGuesser guesser = new MorseCodeGuesser(morseTable);
        List<String> guesses = guesser.guess(code);
        return guesses;
    }

    private static MorseCode convertToMorseCodeWithoutSpaces(String morsetext, MorseTable morseTable) {
        MorseCode code = new MorseCode(morseTable);
        code.fromText(morsetext);
        code.stripSpaces();
        return code;
    }

    private static String enterTextOnConsole() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();
        return text;
    }
}
```

and the following MorseTable class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MorseTable {

    private static final Map<String, String> morseTable;
    private static int longestCode = -1;
    static
    {
        morseTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
        morseTable.put("a", ".-");
        morseTable.put("b", "-...");
        morseTable.put("c", "-.-.");
        morseTable.put("e", ".");
        morseTable.put("t", "-");
        morseTable.put("n", "-.");
        // TODO: add more codes

        for (String code : morseTable.values()) {
            longestCode = Math.max(longestCode, code.length());
        }
    }

    public String getMorseCodeForCharacter(char c) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String characterString = ""+c;
        if (morseTable.containsKey(characterString)) {
            return morseTable.get(characterString);
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No morse code for '"+characterString+"'.");
        }
    }

    public int lengthOfLongestMorseCode() {
        return longestCode;
    }

    public String getTextForMorseCode(String morseCode) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (String key : morseTable.keySet()) {
            if (morseTable.get(key).equals(morseCode)) {
                return key;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No character for morse code '"+morseCode+"'.");
    }
}
```

and the MorseCode class

```
public class MorseCode {

    public MorseCode(MorseTable morseTable)
    {
        _morseTable = morseTable;
    }

    final MorseTable _morseTable;

    String morseCode = "";

    public void fromText(String morsetext) {
        for(int i=0; i<morsetext.length(); i++) {
            char morseCharacter = morsetext.charAt(i);
            morseCode += _morseTable.getMorseCodeForCharacter((morseCharacter));
            morseCode += " "; // pause between characters
        }
    }

    public void stripSpaces() {
        morseCode = morseCode.replaceAll(" ", "");      
    }

    public MorseCode substring(int begin, int end) {
        MorseCode subcode = new MorseCode(_morseTable);
        try{
            subcode.morseCode = morseCode.substring(begin, end);
        } catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException s)  {
            subcode.morseCode = "";
        }
        return subcode;
    }

    public MorseCode substring(int begin) {
        return substring(begin, morseCode.length());
    }

    public String asPrintableString() {
        return morseCode;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return morseCode.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

and last not least, the MorseCodeGuesser

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MorseCodeGuesser {

    private final MorseTable _morseTable;

    public MorseCodeGuesser(MorseTable morseTable) {
        _morseTable = morseTable;
    }

    public List<String> guess(MorseCode code) {
        List<String> wordList = new LinkedList<String>();       
        if (code.isEmpty()) return wordList;

        for(int firstCodeLength=1; firstCodeLength<=_morseTable.lengthOfLongestMorseCode(); firstCodeLength++) {
            List<String> guesses = guess(code, firstCodeLength);
            wordList.addAll(guesses);
        }
        return wordList;
    }

    private List<String> guess(MorseCode code, int firstCodeLength) {
        MorseCode firstCode = code.substring(0, firstCodeLength);
        String firstCharacter;
        try{
            firstCharacter = _morseTable.getTextForMorseCode(firstCode.asPrintableString());
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException i) {
            return new LinkedList<String>(); // no results for invalid code
        }

        MorseCode remainingCode = code.substring(firstCodeLength);      
        if (remainingCode.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
            result.add(firstCharacter); // sole result if nothing is left
            return result;
        }

        List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
        List<String> remainingPossibilities = guess(remainingCode);     
        for (String possibility : remainingPossibilities) {
            result.add(firstCharacter + possibility); // combined results
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to convention and clean code, using capitalised method names confuses things.

Comment: @Holloway: fixed casing.

Comment: @thomas wellar Thank you so much!! for the beautiful code!! the code works only for aet = ".- . -" input even after adding all the alphabets and morse code its not working for the following input infy = ".. -. ..-. -.--" however i've also figured out the mistake in my code now it is working fine!! :)

Comment: @YousufIbrahim: fixed. `<` should have been `<=` in MorseCodeGuesser

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you use a class variable instead of the returned value of the recursive function makes it extremely unclear. Even for you as @Thomas Weller said. You should clarify the possible cases when a count one more letter. I deleted eclipse, hence I coded it in C, I hope I will still help you to understand the algo :(understand char* as string)

```
char morse[26][5] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",
".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};

int countPossibleWord(char* s, int inputSize, int  start, char* buffer, int sizeBuff){
    if(start == inputSize){
        if(sizeBuff == 0) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    char buff[sizeBuff+2];          //
    strncpy(buff, buffer, sizeBuff);//
    buff[sizeBuff] = s[start];      // buff = buff+s[start]
    buff[sizeBuff+1] = '\0';        //
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i){
        //run the equivalent of your map to find a match
        if(strcmp(buff, morse[i]) == 0) 
            return countPossibleWord(s, inputSize, start+1, "", 0) + countPossibleWord(s, inputSize, start+1, buff, sizeBuff+1);
        }
    return countPossibleWord(s, inputSize, start+1, buff, sizeBuff+1);
}
```

Comment: Artu can you explain the algo? and  The reason why i used class variable because when I try to run through the code manually(in paper) i some how lose track of the count when the function returns value and get confused in the mid way. i felt easier to run through(in paper) by using class variable.

Comment: First, you have set your ending condition, which is when you've reach the end of the string, return 0 if the buffer isn't empty, and 1 if it is. That way, the first call to countPoss(…) will create 2 branches (and each of them 2 others branches, …) of possible strings of morse words and those that ends up with an empty buffer <=> that represent the entire initial string will add one to your count.

Comment: Then you add the next char of the string to your buffer: `buff = buff+s[start]`, then you run through the different cases:<br/> 1) the buffer contains a string that is part of the morse table then the possible words that the string will create are those where `buff`is interpreted as a morse word + those where `buff`is only a part of a morse word. <br/> 2) the buffer contains a string that isn't in the morse table, hence you check if by adding the next char to the buffer is will.

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted my own solution to it. I have followed DFS and it is giving the correct answer for the given problem statement. Please ask if there are any queries.

```
    alpha =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    key = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--",
                            "-..-","-.--","--.."]
    dic = dict(list(zip(key,alpha)))

    def morse_code(morse,count,res,char,length):
        global dic
        if count == length - 1:
            if morse[char:] in dic:
                res = res + 1
            return res

        word = ''

        for i in range(char,len(morse)):
            word = word + morse[i]
            if word not in dic:
                continue
            else:
                count = count + 1
                res = morse_code(morse,count,res,i+1,length)
               count = count - 1
        return res
    if __name__ = 'main'
        inp = input()
        morse = ''
        for i in inp:
            morse = morse + key[ord(i)-ord('a')]

        result = morse_code(morse,0,0,0,len(inp))
        print(result)
```